# SharePoint document library not showing actual user's name in 'Modified By' on Custom List's meta-data

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sharepoint-list, powerapps-canvas

I have created an utility for browsing and uploading file from user's machine (OS is Windows10) to a SharePoint site's document library. This utility is created using 1. a canvas form created in Power App, 2. a workflow created in Power Automate and 3. destination document library of SharePoint site.

To briefly summarize about its working; when any user uploads any file using this form, workflow is triggered to store this file as an entry to a SharePoint list, and it is then sent to designated reviewers to get it reviewed and approved. On approval, file is moved from SharePoint list to another site's document library.
Files are successfully being moved to the destination document library.

Here is the problem I'm facing for the moved files - The document library has 'modified by' meta-data column associated with files. This field does not display actual user's name whoever uploads a file or replaces an existing file by uploading a modified version of this file. It always shows my name in 'Modified By' field.

Is there any way to fix this and show the actual user's name in this field who uploads any new file or replaces any existing one.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is by design.
The kind of trigger you are using in SharePoint connector always operate in context of the owner of the flow (you)
Please check the following for detailed description and possible workarounds: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269396/microsoft-flow-always-run-in-context-of-user-who-published-it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 'update file properties'. I have not tested if this works or not, but it seems practical solution to test.

[image]

Comment: Also, check this https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/File-approval-process-in-SharePoint/m-p/4174#M2246